# How would you derive this expression related to transient temperature rise?

Tags: calculus, integration, heat-equation, error-function

I need help with a math problem for math club tomorrow. Its a fun presentation, but I need help with this one problem. Thanks in advance!

Given the transient point source solution valid within an isotropic half space

$T=\frac{q}{2\pi \:kr}erfc\left(\frac{r}{2\sqrt{\alpha \:t}}\right),\:dA\:=\:r\:dr\:d\theta$

derive the expression for the transient temperature rise at the centroid of a circular
area ($\pi a^2$) which is subjected to a uniform and constant heat flux q. Superposition of
point source solutions allows one to write

$T_0=\int _0^a\:\int _0^{2\pi }\:T\:dA$

Here's an exact photo, just in case I wasn't clear originally :).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIaZJ.png

To be clear, I think that one would use the derivative in terms of A and substitute, but I'm not completely sure where to go from there, so it would be very helpful if someone was able to help me be able to solve it. I know what the error function is, but I'm not sure how to use it in this problem. To be clear, I don't need help with my homework, its just for an extracurricular presentation, and I want to be able to teach my fellow math club friends about how to solve an equation like this. It would further our education in the subject, and I think everyone would benefit as a result. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it.